# C++ I cant get my function to run in my program

Tags: c++

The Function won't initiate can someone help? When I run it in the debugger program skips over function and I don't know why?

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int size_array= 0;
int *data_array;
void sorting(int *[], int);


int main()
{
cout<<"enter in array size \n";
 cin>>size_array;
int *data_array=new int(size_array);

 for(int i=0;i<size_array;i++)
  {
   cout<<"enter number "<<i+1<<endl;
   cin>>data_array[i];
  }
 **int sorting(int data_array, int size_array);**

for (int i=0; i<size_array;i++)
  {
    cout<<data_array[i]<<endl;
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me you are in the process of learning C++ (there are more syntax errors in there, so first fix all your compileer errors and warnings), also have a look here : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marked code is simply *declaring* the function, not *calling* it.

Also, your `data_array` is a pointer to a single `int` whose value is initialized as `size_array`. But you want an array of `size_array` number of `int`s instead.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sorting(int[], int);

int main()
{
    int size_array = 0;
    cout << "enter in array size \n";
    cin >> size_array;
    int *data_array = new int[size_array];

    for(int i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter number " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> data_array[i];
    }

    sorting(data_array, size_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        cout << data_array[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] data_array;
    return 0;
}

void sorting(int data_array[], int size_array)
{
    // sort data_array as needed...
}
```